# How to run ruby/javascript code every other day?

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, haml

I'm trying to make a automated watering system I found online, right now the pump only runs when the user presses start and stops when the user presses stop. I would like to have it run every two days. I'm not sure if I need to put it in my javascript water-pump file or my ruby Sinatra app script. I've tried using the clockwork and whenever gem, I think my syntax was wrong I tried putting it around the CLIENT.publish in app.rb. Also in the tutorial I'm following the creator says to add the right parameters to the end  `CLIENT.publish('pump/data', {state:{pump: params['action']}}.to_json)` in the app.rb file. I've also tried to do setInterval in water-pump.js but unsure how to do it. I haven't done anything with the index.haml file do I need to put something in the .pump-control. Here is the tutorial if you wanna look at it https://www.hackster.io/demirhanaydin/waterpi-houseplant-remote-watering-and-monitoring-system-340400

Here is my water-pump.js file

```
function takeAction() {
  var button = $('#pumper'),
      action = $('#action_input').val();

  $('#action-form').trigger('submit');

  if (action == 'start') {
    $('#action_input').val('stop');
    button.text('stop');
  } else {
    $('#action_input').val('start');
    button.text('start');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#action-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: form.attr('method'),
      url: form.attr('action'),
      data: form.serialize()
    }).done(function(data) {
      // Optionally alert the user of success here...
    }).fail(function(data) {
      // Optionally alert the user of an error here...
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my app.rb

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'
require './boot'


set :sessions, true
set :session_secret, SESSION_SECRET

enable :sessions

get '/' do
  haml 'welcome/index'.to_sym
end


post '/take-action' do
  CLIENT.publish('pump/data', {state:{pump: params['action']}}.to_json)
  200
 end
```

And here is my index.haml file

```
%head
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('javascripts/jquery.min.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/water-pump.js')}
  %iframe{:align => "center",:height => "450", :src => "https://app.redash.io/taylor/embed/query/76316/visualization/132291?api_key=EfPwD8WgLKybMagKriu7JrLFXvYWpVVQrV5g0qqp", :width => "820",:style => "float:left;margin-top:30px;"}
  %link{rel: :stylesheet, type: :"text/css", href: url('/stylesheets/default.css')}
#container
  #synchronized
  .gauge
    #container-speed
    .pump-control
      %form{method: :post, action: '/take-action', id: 'action-form' }
        %input{type: 'hidden', name: 'action', value: 'start', id: 'action_input'}
        %span{:align => "center",id: 'pumper', onclick: 'takeAction()'}
          start
```

Comment: What is cron? What are intervals?

Comment: Could I just node scheduler?

Comment: how would i do it at the end CLIENT.publish('pump/data', {state:{pump: params['action']}}.to_json)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a [cron job](https://serverfault.com/questions/204265/how-to-configure-cron-job-to-run-every-2-days-at-11pm) to schedule your system.

- Schedule your cron job to run every X hours/minutes (whatever is reasonable for your system)
- Configure your cron job to execute a script that hits an API endpoint or queries your database directly.  Check for any watering jobs that need to be stopped or started and execute them.

I suggest cron or some other trust worthy scheduling system because it is dangerous rely on a long running application to keep the schedule.  It is also considered good design to build components that are good at only one thing so that you can test them in isolation.

Comment: Would I turn takeAction into a cron?

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily need to make takeAction into a cron job, but you could do something like `curl https://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/takeAction`.  That way you can keep the takeAction logic in your web application.  Just use the cron to trigger the action.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cron

Comment: I'm just unsure where to put the cron job